# Closing a path with too sharps edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

The "oval" path in too sharp as you can see in the intersection with the horizontal line. How can i fix this problem?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}  

 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]

 \draw[smooth,pattern=north east lines] (0,0) to[out=75,in=285] (0,7.5)   to[out=255,in=105] (0,0)-- cycle;
 \draw (0,-7.5) to[out=105,in=255] (0,0);

 \draw (0,7.5)--(20,7.5);
 \draw (0,-7.5)--(20,-7.5);

  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "too sharp"? Is it the problem with the miter join? if so this was already answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176980/12571), in the final part, wasn't?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what you desire but just tweak the `in` and `out` angles to suit. Here they are with a `20` degree change, and a `thick` line style:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}  

 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]

 \draw[smooth,pattern=north east lines,thick] (0,0) to[out=55,in=305] (0,7.5)   to[out=235,in=125] (0,0)-- cycle;
 \draw [thick] (0,-7.5) to[out=125,in=235] (0,0);

 \draw (0,7.5)--(20,7.5);
 \draw (0,-7.5)--(20,-7.5);

  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```